# I'm capturing screen by using media recorder and making video from blob but that video is not showing it's duration

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video, blob, getid3

I'm capturing screen by using media recorder and making video from blob but that video is not showing it's duration i have tried all way but not able to get the duration.
I used get getID3(PHP) but not working i used many other ways but only one way works for me which where two steps i have defined below:|

```
var vid = document.createElement("video");
vid.src = url;
object.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
                                if(vid.duration === Infinity) {
                                    vid.currentTime = 1000000000; 
                                }  
                            });

                            var duration = 0;
                            var speed_factor = 0.0;
                            object.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
                                duration = vid.duration;
                                if(duration <= 10.0)
                                {
                                    speed_factor = 1.0;
                                }else if(duration <= 30.0)
                                {
                                    speed_factor = 1.5;
                                }else if(duration <= 60.0)
                                {
                                    speed_factor = 2.0;
                                }else if(duration <= 120.0)
                                {
                                    speed_factor = 3.0;
                                }else if(duration <= 180.0)
                                {
                                    speed_factor = 4.0;
                                }else if(duration <= 240.0)
                                {
                                    speed_factor = 5.0;
                                }else{
                                    speed_factor = 10.0;
                                }
                                $("#source1").attr("src", url);
                                $("#source2").attr("src", url);
                                
                                $("#videoplayer").get(0).defaultPlaybackRate = speed_factor;
                                console.log("The video duration is "+ duration+" and speed factor is "+speed_factor);

                                $('#videoplayer').get(0).load();
                                $('#videoplayer').get(0).play();
                            });
```